# AttributeError: module 'MyModule' has no attribute 'Module1'

Tags: python, package, python-wheel

I am trying to turn a project of mine into a package so I can deploy it as a wheel.
I have a project directory setup like this:

```
ProjectDir
├── setup.py
├── MyModule
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── Module1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── main.py
│   ├── Module2
│   │   ├── file1.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── file2.py
│   │   ├── file3.py
│   └── Module3
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── Sub1
│       │   ├── file1.py
│       │   ├── file2.py
│       │   ├── main.py
│       └── Sub2
│           ├── file1.py
│           ├── main.py
└── test
    ├── test_Module_1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_main.py
    ├── test_Module_2
    ...
```

Top level __init__.py is empty
Module 1 __init__.py file

```
from main import Function1
```

Similar for other module __init__.py files

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import os
import pip

setup(name='MyModule',
    description='Tool suite to run MyModule',
    packages=['MyModule'])
```

I can import MyModule but when I attempt to access any submodule, I get the following

> AttributeError: module 'MyModule' has no attribute 'Module1'
> Or if I check attributes of my module, none are found.

```
import MyModule
dir(MyModule)
```

> ['**builtins**', '**cached**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**loader**', '**name**', '**package**', '**path**', '**spec**', 'os']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected because by default submodules are not imported.
You should import them like so to use them:

```
import MyModule.Module1
```

To change this you have to tweak the `MyModule/__init__.py` file by adding:

```
import MyModule.Module1
```

This way, `MyModule.Module1` will be available when you import `MyModule`, as the `__init__.py` file is executed.